# Interpolation in uniform data grid with weighted corner points

Tags: c#, math, interpolation

**Here is my current situation:**
I have a 2 dimensional uniform grid of points where each point has an associated float value.
`7---2`
`| . |`
`2---1`

I can interpolate the values between those points using bi-linear interpolation:

```
    public float GetValue(float x, float y, float topLeft, float topRight, 
                          float bottomLeft, float bottomRight)
    {
       return topLeft*(1-x)*(1-y) + topRight*x*(1-y) + 
              bottomLeft*(1-x)*y + bottomRight*x*y;
    }
```

Now I need to add a weight to each point that determines how strong its influence is on its surrounding area.
For example: If all 4 points have the same weight values then those weights cancel each other out and the interpolation would return the exact same values as the unweighted version.
Now let's say all points have a weight of 1 except the point in the bottom left corner which has a weight value of 2. In that case its value will influence the interpolation twice as much as the other values and the interpolation will shift in favor of the value located in bottom left corner.

Basically I'm trying to implement a method like this:

```
    public float GetValue(float x, float y, float topLeftValue, topLeftWeight, 
                          float topRightValue, float topRightWeight,  
                          float bottomLeftValue, float bottomLeftWeight, 
                          float bottomRightValue, float bottomRightWeight)
    {
       return ?  
    }
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this? Is there a equation/algorithm or a modification of the bi-linear interpolation method that considers weighted corner values?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So multiply the weights by the values and use those in your bilinear interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

To make the thing easier, assume x = y = 0.5

If all 4 points have the same weight values, the return value should be

```
return topLeftValue/4 + topRightValue/4 + bottomLeftValue/4 + bottomRightValue/4;
```

Now, let all points have a weight of 1 except the point in the bottom left corner which has a weight value of 2, the return value should be

```
return topLeftValue/5 + topRightValue/5 + bottomLeftValue*2/5 + bottomRightValue/5;
```

The weight of bottomLeftValue is adjusted by multiplying

`4*bottomLeftWeight / (topLeftWeight+topRightWeight+bottomLeftValue+bottomRightWeight)`

Now, back to the general cases.
Use the above method to adjust the weight of each value.
It will become

```
float overallWeight = topLeftWeight + topRightWeight + bottomLeftValue + bottomRightWeight;
```

`return topLeftValue*(1-x)*(1-y)*(4*topLeftWeight/overallWeight) 
+ topRightValue*x*(1-y)*(4*topRightWeight/overallWeight) 
+ bottomLeftValue*(1-x)*y*(4*bottomLeftWeight/overallWeight) 
+ bottomRightValue*x*y*(4*bottomRightWeight/overallWeight)`